# Proving that $g(z)$ is bounded in a neighborhood $N(c,\delta)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I need help understanding a proof that appears in "Complex Analysis" by John M. Howie.

**The theorem**

Suppose that $f$ has a simple pole at $c$, with residue $\rho$, and let $\gamma^*$ be a circular arc with radius $r$:

$$\gamma(\theta)=c+re^{i\theta}$$

Then $$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz=i\rho(\beta-\alpha)$$

**The Proof**

In a suitable neighborhood $N(c,\delta)$ we have a Laurent expansion $$f(z)=\frac{\rho}{z-c}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\,a_n(z-c)^n$$

If we define $g(z)$ as $f(z)-(\rho/(z-c))$, we see that $g$ is bounded in $N(c,\delta)$. That is, there exists $M>0$ such that $\vert g(z)\vert\leq M...$

**What I don't understand**

I don't know why $g(z)$ is bounded in $N(c,\delta)$. What is the reason why $g(z)$ is bounded? Also, I don't understand what a "suitable neighborhood" refers to. Could someone please explain? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-c)^n$$ so that $g$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $c$. As for suitable neighborhood, it just refers to a neighborhood such that the Laurent expansion is valid (this is always guaranteed to exist for an isolated singularity).